# Find most fat directories by it's own size

Tags: linux, bash, du

I would like to list most fat directories by it's own size sorted by size descending.
'Directory own size' means size of the directory excluding size of all it's subdirectories.

For example, we have directory structure:

```
    /tmp/D1
            |-- 5m.file
            |-- D2
            |   |-- 2m.file
            |   `-- D4
            |       `-- 4m.file
            `-- D3
                `-- 3m.file
```

By for executing command and passing /tmp/D1 as argument I'd like to get result like

```
    5m      /tmp/D1
    4m      /tmp/D1/D2/D4
    3m      /tmp/D1/D3
    2m      /tmp/D1/D2
```

---

```
du -Sh . | sort -rh | head -n 10
```

+x to limit to current filesystem only

```
du -Shx . | sort -rh | head -n 10
```

Comment: `du -sh * | sort -rh`?

Comment: it gives different result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `du` with an `-S` option for this

From the `man` page

> -S, --separate-dirs
>             do not include size of subdirectories

```
$ du -Sh /foo/bar/temp2/ | sort -rh

84K     /foo/bar/temp2/
40K     /foo/bar/temp2/tempo
4.0K    /foo/bar/temp2/opt/logs/merchantportal
4.0K    /foo/bar/temp2/opt/logs
4.0K    /foo/bar/temp2/opt
4.0K    /foo/bar/temp2/folder
4.0K    /foo/bar/temp2/bang
```

Now checking in the normal way with the `-s` option, which is inclusive of all sub-directories.

```
$ du -sh /foo/bar/temp2/opt
12K     /foo/bar/temp2/opt
```

which is the summation of sizes of the sub-folders `/foo/bar/temp2/opt/logs/merchantportal`, `/foo/bar/temp2/opt/logs` and the base folder itself

The `-h` formats the size in the human readable format according to the `man` page. If you forcefully want to format the output in 1-Mbyte blocks you can use the option `du -Sm`

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for `du -Sh . | sort -rh | less`